# vue js 2.x, Nested v-slot {scoped slot} not working with the childs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use nested v slot in vue js but the pb is that the child component componentC is not getting the value "valueB". Also  the componentC is not getting the value "valueA".

Reproduction link

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-diffie-x3tq0?f

**My parent.vue**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <component-a>
      <template v-slot:b="{valueA}">
        <component-b :value=valueA>
            <template v-slot:C="{valueB}">
              <component-c :value=valueB >
               </component-c>
            </template>
        </component-b>
      </template>
      </component-a>
</div>
```

**My child component templates**

```
 Vue.component('ComponentA', {
  template: '<slot name="b" :value="valueA"/>',
  data: function() {
    return {
    valueA: 1
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('ComponentB', {
  template: '<slot name="c" :value="valueB"/>',
  props: ["valueFromA"],
  data: function() {
    return {
    valueB: 0
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('ComponentC', {
  template: '<div> {{ valueFromB}}</div>',
  props: ["valueFromB"],
  data: function() {
    return {
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    valueA: '50'
  })
})
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be achieved.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.component('ComponentA', {
  template: `<div>
    <h4>component A value from itself: {{valueA}}</h4>
    <slot name="b" :value="valueA"/>
  </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    valueA: 1
  })
})
Vue.component('ComponentB', {
  template: `<div>
    <h4>component B value from A: {{value}}</h4>
    <h4>component B valueB from itself: {{valueB}}</h4>
    <slot name="c" :value="value" :valueB="valueB"/>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number]
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    valueB: 2 + 2
  })

});
Vue.component('ComponentC', {
  template: `<div>
  <h4>component C valueA from component A: {{ valueA }}</h4>
  <h4>component C value from component B: {{ value }}</h4>
  <h4>component C valueB from component B: {{ valueB }}</h4>
  <h4>component C valueC from itself: {{ valueC }}</h4>
  <slot></slot>
</div>`,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number]
    },
    valueA: {
      type: [String, Number]
    },
    valueB: {
      type: [String, Number]
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    valueC: -2
  })
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: () => ({
    testAppInC: 'this is a test...'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component-a v-slot:b="foo">
    <component-b :value="foo.value" v-slot:c="bar">
    <!-- Or: <component-b v-bind="foo" v-slot:c="bar"> -->
    <!-- Or: <component-b v-bind="{value: foo.value}" v-slot:c="bar"> -->
      <component-c v-bind="{...bar, valueA: foo.value}">{{testAppInC}}</component-c>
      <!-- above line is equivalent to:
      <component-c v-bind="bar" :value-a="foo.value">{{testAppInC}}</component-c>
  Or: <component-c :value="bar.value" :value-b="bar.valueB" :value-a="foo.value">...
  Or: <component-c v-bind="{value: bar.value, valueB: bar.valueB, valueA: foo.value}">...

  Anything from app level is still available at any other level.
      -->
    </component-b>
  </component-a>
</div>
```

`component-b`'s properties are available inside of `component-c` as whatever you named it in `<template v-slot:c="someName">`. In the case above, `whatever`.

Comment: Thanks. even me i can not understand how your code is working.  But you may be misunderstanding my question because i want to send valueA from component A to component B, do some work then send valueB from component B to component C.

Comment: Hmm. I was certain `valueA` was also available inside the controller, not only inside the template. I'll try to come up with a proper solution.

Comment: I created https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-diffie-x3tq0?f to be as ruuning code.

Comment: Found the proper answer. You have to name the binding to any name at `component-b` level and then use the same name at `component-c` level. Here's the link to your [fixed codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-lake-u4ttr?file=/src/App.vue). I'll update my answer accordingly.